# Bott's Formula and Blow up

Tags: examples-counterexamples, sheaf-cohomology, blowup

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^{n}$ and $Z \subset X$  a smooth subvariety with $\text{dim}(Z) > 0$.

A very useful tool for calculating cohomologies in $X$ is the **Bott's Formula** below enunciated:

$$h^{q}(\mathbb{P}^{n}, \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^{p}(k)) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
{k+n-p \choose k}{k-1 \choose p},& \mbox{for} & q = 0,\,0\leq p\leq n, \,k> p\\
1, & \mbox{for} & k = 0\,\ 0<p = q \leq n\\
{-k+p \choose -k}{-k-1 \choose n-p}, & \mbox{for}\,\,q = n & 0 \leq p\leq n, \,\ k < p-n \\
0, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
In particular for $p = 0$ we have:

$$h^{q}(\mathbb{P}^{n}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(k)) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
{k+n\choose k} ,& \mbox{for} & q = 0, \,k \geq 0\\
{-k-1 \choose -k-1-n}, & \mbox{for} & q = n,\,\  0 \leq p\leq n, \,\ k < p-n \\
0, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Let $\pi : \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be the blow up of $X$ along of $Z$.

Is Bott's formula valid in $\widetilde{X}$?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Allan, I think these formulas don't hold for a blow-up. Why do you expect the result will be independent of $Z$ ? Have you tried to compute these when $Z$ is a line in $\Bbb P^3$ ?

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Are you all right?  Exactly. I also think that Bott's formula is not valid in $\widetilde{X} $, so I am trying to display a counterexample when $Z$ is a line in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$, but to no avail so far.

Comment: I think it will depend on the center of the blow up (see this answer which I also offered a bounty  Zlatan Ramovic (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/700541/zlatan-ramovic), Blow up and relationship between tangents sheaves ). The of center codimension is used to describe the tangent sheaf of the blow up.Therefore, I think that by dualizing to find the cotangent sheaf, the exceptional divider will contribute to the calculation of cohomology. Thank you for your attention to the question.